# understanding fputc

Tags: c, fopen, getchar

I am trying to get a basic understanding on how to use fputc in C. I have read some documentation that is out there and believed I had it right. But every time I try to use the script I wrote by executing **./fputc > test.txt** where **text.txt** is a text file with one line of text.

This is my script:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv){
    int ch;
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("text.txt", "w+");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF){
        fputc(ch, input);
    }
    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}
```

I get no errors on compilation and for some reason the script does not reach EOF at the end of the text file. Shouldn't the getchar return EOF when it reached the end of the text file?
The text (text.txt) file does not appear to be edited, although it is created. So somewhere in my while loop something is going wrong.

I am new to C programming (if you couldn't tell) and this little script has me befuddled.

Any help would be appreciated, or any links to sites with further detail would also be great.

Cheers,

S.

Comment: `./fputc > test.txt` will truncate `test.txt`. Do you have two files (test.txt and text.txt)? Are you trying to use one as input? (It is really not clear.)

Comment: This code fails to check the result of the `fopen` call to determine if it was successful, though this is not the cause of the current problem.   It should also check the result of `fclose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you in essence say is:

- Console: Run *my_program* and write anything it outputs to te**s**t.txt.
- Program: Open te**x**t.txt and write any input to stdin to that file.

---

Your console normally have three standard streams [`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). These streams you can [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29). If you are on Windows also look at i.e. [redirection](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

When you say `./my_prog > test.txt`, what you tell your console, (not `my_prog`), is to write anything `my_prog` writes to `stdout` to the file `test.txt`.

If you in your code say i.e. `printf("Hello");`, then *Hello* would be written to the file `test.txt`.

If you had turned your redirection around by saying `./my_prog < test.txt` instead, would be; *stream the file test.txt to my_prog*. Which, in turn, if there was any text in *test.txt* would result in a copy of test.txt to text.txt.

Now in your code you say:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int ch;
    FILE *input;

    /* Here you open a handle to the file text.txt for reading and writing */
    input = fopen("text.txt", "w+");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { /* get next char from stdin */
        fputc(ch, input); /* write that char to the handle input */
    }
    fclose(input); /* close the handle */

    return 0;
}
```

So what happens, the way you run it, is:

In your code:

1. Open text.txt
2. Wait for input (data entered to stdin) - typically user entering text to console, passed to program when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

In console:

1. Redirect anything from `my_prog` to test.txt.

---

You say:

> the script does not reach EOF

Well, as it reads from `stdin` it will only (not without exception) get EOF under two conditions.

1. If you redirect a file to your program. I.e. `./my_prog < foo.txt` (notice `<`, not `>`).
         - What would happen then is that `my_prog` would read the data from the file `foo.txt` and when that file ends your program would receive a EOF. And, hence quit.
2. If you manually enter EOF to `stdin`.
         - On Linux and OSX <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, on Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

---

Now, if you test this by typing text to console remember that write actions like `fputc()`is buffered. What this mean is that the data is not written to the file right away, but only when a given amount of data is in buffer, `fflush()` is called, stream is closed, you turn off buffering, etc.

Also; if you run your program. Enter text, enter some more text, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to abort the program it is a big chance you end with no data in your `text.txt`.

The reason for this is that the program is killed and thereby `fclose()` never called, and hence no flush to file.

---

On your further endeavors in programming it would be a very good idea to make a habit of not presuming anything. I.e. do not presume `fopen()` is OK.

```
FILE *fh;
char *outfile = "foo.txt";

if ((fh = fopen(outfile, "w")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Unable to open file %s\n --",
            outfile);
    perror(" fopen() ");
    return 1;
}
```

Most functions has a way to check if operation was a success. I.e:

```
if (fputc(ch, fh) != ch) { err ...
```

This will make your code a lot safer, give you hints on where it fails etc.

---

Some links:

- Look at redirection links at top of post.
- Look at the functions in [stdio.h (good overview)](http://www.utas.edu.au/infosys/info/documentation/C/CStdLib.html#stdio.h), [stdio.h (examples etc.)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/). I.e.:

  - [stdin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stdin/)
  - [stdout](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stdout/)
  - [stderr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/stderr/)
  - [fopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)
  - [fflush()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fflush/)
  - [setvbuf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setvbuf/)
  - [setbuf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/setbuf/)
  - ...

Answer (score 0):

getchar returns the next character from the standard input (stdin).
It is equivalent to getc with stdin as its argument.

Hence, your code reads from standard input instead of FILE* input.

Use fgetc here.
fgetc returns the character currently pointed by the internal file position indicator of the specified stream. The internal file position indicator is then advanced by one character to point to the next character.

So, Use fgetc to read from a file:

```
while ((ch = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

your program and the shell are both writing the same file. you should remove the output redirection `> test.txt` from your command line